# VBA program stops to refresh the worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, updates

I'm making my own [Conway's Game of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life) on VBA where the current state is displayed on a worksheet.
Because I'm not skilled, the implementation is probably not very efficient (I use 2 boolean matrices to model the current state and the next one).
To display the result at each step, I've `sub display()` that took the `matrix_current`and color each cell in black or white. To make the whole process smoother, I've wrapped `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`and `Application.ScreenUpdating = True`. Short story long, it looks like that :

```
Private Sub display()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For i = 0 To sizeGrid
    For j = 0 To sizeGrid
        If matrix_curr(i, j) Then
            Cells(i + xmin, j + ymin).Interior.ColorIndex = 1
        Else
            Cells(i + xmin, j + ymin).Interior.ColorIndex = 2
        End If
    Next
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Before each `Call display()` I call the method `Sleep()` to let enough time to watch each step.

So, here is my issue:
The display on the worksheet often stops after a small amount of steps. However, the program is still running and finally shows the last state. So basically, I can monitor the beginning, then nothing change until the last step that is displayed.
Everything happen as if the worksheet suddenly stop to be refreshed.

Do you have any idea to solve this issue.

I thank you in advance for your help (and hope that I make myself understood
despite my poor English)

Comment: Let me make sure I understand you correctly. You turn off screen updating and now you want to know why your screen isn't updating? Please correct me if I have mistaken.

Comment: if you refer to `Application.ScreenUpdating = True/False`, it is just to have all cells changed at once. I had the same issue before adding this.
What it does is just "freezing" the screen while the two loops are done, and then I release the screen. 

My problem is that after a number of steps, nothing more happen on the screen (as if it was freeze). But it works perfectly well at the beginning.

Comment: Use `Doevents` in your code to ensure repainting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *My problem is that after a number of steps, nothing more happen on the screen (as if it was freeze).*

That's because Excel is essentially running out of breath - it's basically not keeping up with all the `ScreenUpdating` toggles.

When you toggle `Application.ScreenUpdating` back on *once*, Excel happily responds by repainting itself.

When you're running a busy loop, it's prioritizing execution of the VBA code and the Excel UI goes:

```
(not responding)
```

This is normal: there's a lot of things to process, so it's processing them - updating the UI, raising worksheet events, responding to user actions, calculating cells, all these things "drop priority", until the VBA code completes.

Try adding a `DoEvents` instruction immediately after toggling `Application.ScreenUpdating` back on; this explicitly tells Excel "okay, go ahead, process whatever other stuff you've got, then come back here when you're ready". I'd warmly recommend leaving `Application.EnableEvents` off and `Application.Calculation` set to `xlCalculationManual` until the code completely executed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll give it a try as soon as possible. 
Where do you set `Application.EnableEvents` off `Application.Calculation`? In the declaration ?

Comment: I need to perform few more tests but I think it works. Thanks a lot ! I had no idea what `DoEvents` was made for but it seems to be both powerfull and dangerous to use this in VBA.